# "PackageUriForbidden" error when trying to deploy an Azure Cloud Service ES

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azureportal

I am trying to redeploy an Azure Cloud Service (classic) to an "extended support" one since the former is being deprecated. Following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cloud-services-extended-support/deploy-portal) and [the prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cloud-services-extended-support/deploy-prerequisite) I have created a virtual network and new storage account. I set up a bunch of permissions and the **Connectivity Check** for my storage account indicates no problems. However when I try to create and deploy a new Cloud Service (Extended Support) using my (updated) .cscfg, .csdef and .cspkg files I get this error:

> Error:AuthorizationFailure,  message:This request is not authorized to perform this operation. (Code: PackageUriForbidden)

I've tried setting the container and blob access to public for the deploy files, I have added **Network Contributor** and **Storage Blob Data Contributor** to both the subscription and the cloud storage resources for my user account. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried deploying cloud services extended support via Azure Portal and it got deployed successfully.
Refer below :-

[image]

I have uploaded all my cloud services packages in my storage account and used those packages from my storage blobs and created the Cloud service ES instance.

**I enabled connection from all networks for my storage account, Thus I did not receive any authorization error**  :-

[image]

*It looks like your Storage account has Firewall and V-Net enabled for the selected Networks. Or There’s an IP Address added to restrict storage account.*

I created a Create a Service endpoint in my V-Net to allow Microsoft.storage like below :-

[image]

Added this V-Net in the selected Networks in Storage account’s Firewall :-

[image]

Checked this in order to allow azure services to access storage account like below :-

[image]

Now, when I try to deploy another cloud service with the same storage account having firewall and V-Net enabled, I get the same error as yours refer below :-

[image]

I allowed my client machine’s IP in the storage account and was able to add the packages without any error while deploying the Cloud Service:-

[image]

Comment: Thank you! For me, it seems all I had left to do for my case was the first step, enable public access from all networks for the storage account.